# Get only first class of an HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, class, dom-events, classname

I'm using the

```
event.target.className
```

to get the `ClassName`, but sometimes an element has multiple class names, how can I make it,
so it **only** gives the **first class** name as outcome?

Oh, and please without jQuery.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There are various ways to get first class of an element

> **Method first** : Using className property

Using the className property of DOM elements with the split function which will split className by spaces and return an array.

```
event.target.className.split(" ")[0]; //0 to retrieve first class
```

The className property is supported in all major browsers.

> **Method second** : Using classList property

Using the classList property of DOM elements which return a [DOMTokenList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMTokenList) Object of classes(already split by space)

```
event.target.classList[0]; //0 to retrieve first class
```

The classList property is relatively new and relatively faster too.
This is not supported in IE8 and IE9. **[Support in various browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist)**

[Check performance of classList vs className](http://jsperf.com/classlist-firstclass-vs-classname-firstclass)

Answer (score 0):

If you'd want target the element to which the event handler has been attached use this

`event.currentTarget.classList[0]`